# How to change System Date Time from UWP App

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a requirement to change System's date time from UWP app.
I am trying below methods but it is not working. Same methods works if I run from Console App.

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SYSTEMTIME
    {
        public short wYear;
        public short wMonth;
        public short wDayOfWeek;
        public short wDay;
        public short wHour;
        public short wMinute;
        public short wSecond;
        public short wMilliseconds;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern SYSTEMTIME GetSystemTime();
    
    public void ChangeDateTime()
    {
                SYSTEMTIME a = GetSystemTime();
                SYSTEMTIME st = new SYSTEMTIME();
                st.wYear = (short)a.wYear;
                st.wMonth = (short)a.wMonth;
                st.wDay = (short)a.wDay;
                st.wHour = (short)a.wHour;
                st.wMinute = (short)(a.wMinute + 5);
                st.wSecond = (short)a.wSecond;
                st.wMilliseconds = (short)a.wMilliseconds;

                bool i = SetSystemTime(ref st);
    }
```

SetSystemTime returns false and Date time doesn't get effected.

Is there something I am missing or any is there any other way to do it?

Comment: The problem might be in security restrictions, try to run a program as an administrator

Comment: Who gave that requirement to you and why? Usually, you'd want a system's date and time be synchronized to a time server.

Comment: HI @GeorgeKarlinzer, Don't know how to run an UWP as administrator.

Comment: @Fildor , App will run in kiosk mode and client want this functionality. Also there will not be internet connection so we can't sync time with server.

Comment: "Client want" is not a good reason, but running off-grid would have been an important piece of information to add to the question.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the document- [SetSystemTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-setsystemtime), this method only works in desktop apps. It is expected that this method is not working in UWP apps.

UWP apps are running in the sandbox and having limited access to the system resources. There is a native UWP API that could set the system date - [DateTimeSettings.SetSystemDateTime(DateTime) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.datetimesettings.setsystemdatetime?view=winrt-22621). But it **only works for IOT devices** not on desktop.

The only way is that you could use the API in a console app. Then launch the console app from the UWP app. You could try to refer to Stefan's blog about how to implement this: https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/

Comment: Native UWP API is [DateTimeSettings.SetSystemDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.datetimesettings.setsystemdatetime). Requires `systemManagement` capability and available only when the system is in IoT mode.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you for the heads up. It was an oversight on my part.

Comment: Hi @RoyLi-MSFT ,  I read Stefan Wick's blog and it seems helpful. I created desktop app to change system date time and ran it with full trust from UWP. That is working but still trying to add App Service to add communication between UWP and Desktop app to get more control.